# Backand: Cyrillic strings turn to?

Tags: backand

After sending POST or PUT request got rows added but Cyrillic strings turned to ?????.

Also when trying to enter and save cyrilic strings through backand dashboard the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Backand's instructions of how to set multi-language-

> On the table where you want to use multi-languages run :
>
> ALTER TABLE database.table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
>
> On each VARCHAR column on that table run :
>
> ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER
>   SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

For more information -

http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/what_would_you_like_to_do/i18n/index.html